# Them after she and her

Tags: grammar, pronouns, gender

I’ve come across the following sentence:

To encourage empathy in your child, encourage your child to talk about **her** feelings and make sure **she** knows that you care about **them**. ([Source](https://www.verywellfamily.com/how-to-raise-a-good-child-620110))

Why is *them* used at the end of the sentence, after *her* and *she*? I know that we can use *they/them* when the gender is not clear, but in this case we do have the *she/her* pronouns, so I’d expect *her*, not *them*.

Comment: 'Them' refers to the feelings and not the child. See the following sentence from your source: "When a conflict occurs with a friend, ask her to imagine how her friend might be feeling and show her ways of managing her emotions and work positively toward a resolution."

Comment: @JMB makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Whether or not JMB's interpretation is "correct", it didn't occur to me until I read that comment. Although I'd consider it a "mistake" to include singular "they" in the same utterance as a gender-specific pronoun, this kind of mistake occurs often enough that I initially parsed the sentence on that basis. In short, it's an awkward example text that perhaps should have been rephrased.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the existence of the question and the highlighting of the pronouns predisposes the reader to interpret "them" as erroneous, whereas if readers read the whole passage, with no highlights and no questions about the pronouns, they would be more likely to interpret it correctly.